# Stop NSTokenField from trimming whitespace

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextfield

I'm trying to set a stringValue to an NSTokenField (a subclass of NSTextField), but I've found that if the string starts with a space, it removes it. I want to keep the space. I tried applying a formatter with no luck as well. i.e.:

```
tokenField.stringValue = " 1"
```

This will actually readout "1" in the field.

Also, I want to format an integer but also keep zeros before it. i.e.:

```
    tokenField.stringValue = "001"
```

This will also readout "1" in the field.

I've tried overriding various functions with no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to check the text field's formatter. Are you using a xib/storyboard?

Comment: I found a partial solution and that was in making a custom solution. The issue is that I'm using a NSTokenField which is a subclass of NSTextField. Applying a formatter doesn't seem to work properly on it..

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `NSTokenField`? There's something about whitespace-trimming.

Comment: @Willeke I have. I haven't found anything that solves my issue though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation of NSTokenField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstokenfield):

> In OS X v10.4, NSTokenField trims whitespace around tokens but it does not trim whitespace in macOS versions 10.5.0 and 10.5.1. In OS X v10.5.2, you get whitespace-trimming behavior by either linking against the v10.4 binary or linking against the v10.5 binary and not implementing the
>   tokenField(_:representedObjectForEditing:)
>   method. If you do not want the whitespace-trimming behavior, link against the v10.5 binary and implement this method, returning the editing string if you have no represented object.

Ok, it it a bit old and the name of the method isn't correct but it says:

> If you do not want the whitespace-trimming behavior, implement tokenField(_:representedObjectForEditingString:), returning the editing string if you have no represented object.

Comment: Ah! I thought I was implementing that function. now I am. Thanks!